# simple question about sql server and c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I cant ponder how to do that. We have clients who use our transportation service. I constructed sql server table with name Debt its relationed with transportation ID and client ID. Clients always pay money at end of month. How can i do with c# or sql server that count all entries from month begining to end of month ?
Sorry for my bad English.
I hope that my question is understandable.
Please Advice me something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute your date in place of `myDateColumnName` and it will give you all the count for the current month -

```
select count(*) from debt
where Month(myDateColumnName) = Month(getdate())
```

If you already know the month number, for eg:- 10, then -

```
select count(*) from debt
where Month(myDateColumnName) = 10
```

Any further conditions to satisfy your criteria, you can add to the given query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE PayDate >= '2010-11-01T00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql would be something similar to:

```
select count(*)
from Debt
where startdate > '01/01/2010' and enddate < '31/01/2010'
```

Obviously substitute those dates above.  You might want to play around with => and <= depending on exactly what date range you're looking for.

This will return a single integer which is the count.

In order to get it into your app you'll need to take a look at the [System.Data.SqlClient namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx)

Comment: use `enddate < '01/02/2010'`, as "< 31/01" doesn't use that date. "<=" doesn't help, that includes just "31-01 0:00".

Comment: Fair enough - like I said the where clause likely needs playing around with depending on the askers requirements